# How to change the length of an edge in TreeLayout JUNG?

Tags: java, jung, jung2

I know how to change the size of the vertex, but when I do that, the TreeLayout places the nodes such that the edges vanish ie. the nodes overlap and the edges are not visible. If I change the layout (to KKLayout), the edges are automatically made larger and the graph looks clean. I want to know if it is possible to space the nodes apart/increase length of an edge in the TreeLayout itself?
(Any other suggestions maintaining the tree hierarchy are also great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the space between nodes when you construct your `TreeLayout`. This would increase the edge length:

```
TreeLayout treeLayout = new TreeLayout<String, Integer>(graph, 500, 500);
```

If you don't enter a value for `distx` or `disty`then it defaults to 50. Constructor:

```
/**
 * Creates an instance for the specified graph, X distance, and Y distance.
 */
public TreeLayout(Forest<V,E> g, int distx, int disty) {
    if (g == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Graph must be non-null");
    if (distx < 1 || disty < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("X and Y distances must each be positive");
    this.graph = g;
    this.distX = distx;
    this.distY = disty;
    buildTree();
}
```

Comment: Do I have to extend the TreeLayout class and over-ride the constructor?

Comment: no, just use the given constructor. It's already in the TreeLayout's class.